# create api doc with swagger

Tags: java, spring, swagger, api-doc

I tried generate some api via swagger
without spring boot
but it doesn't work

my swagger controller class

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/srs/api")
public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    @RequestMapping(value = "/v2/api-docs", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Docket swaggerconf() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo("2.0"))
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
    private ApiInfo apiInfo(String version) {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("API")
                .description("REST API")
                .version(version)
                .build();
    }
}
```

url is mapped

```
Mapped "{[/srs/api/v2/api-docs],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket com.my.applications.srs.rest.controllers.SwaggerConfig.swaggerconf()
```

But the documentation is not created
did i miss something?
may be I can use SpringBoot on server?

Comment: Do you depends too on the `springfox-swagger-ui` dependency?

Comment: @NicolasLabrot sure
i added all necessary dependencies

Comment: Do your logs contain `Mapped "{[/swagger-resources/configuration/ui]}"` ?

Comment: @NicolasLabrot but i need to generate only json

Comment: >Do your logs contain Mapped "{[/swagger-resources/configuration/ui]}" ? – Nicolas Labrot 1 min ago

don't contain

Comment: I thought it is necessary for ui

Comment: So what does not work? `/srs/api/v2/api-docs` does not return json?

Comment: @NicolasLabrot yes

Comment: `@Configuration` classes annotated with `@Controller` which extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` with a `@RequestMapping` on a `Docket` seems a little weird to me. Have you look at [the swagger sample](https://github.com/springfox/springfox-demos/tree/master/boot-swagger) ?

Comment: I runned swagger sample on tomcat
like SpringBoot app
and it's work

Comment: I post an answer with a configuration proposal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try to update your swagger configuration to:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket swaggerconf() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo("2.0"))
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
    private ApiInfo apiInfo(String version) {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("API")
                .description("REST API")
                .version(version)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Then import (if not already done) `@Import` this configuration into your `Application` like class.

When you bootstrap your application you should have a log like

```
 Mapped "{[/v2/api-docs],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json || application/hal+json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.Json> springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller.getDocumentation(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
```

And if you open the url `/v2/api-docs` you should get a json

Comment: Thanks for the advice
I runned with your config, but in logs i can't find Mapper /v2/api-docs :(

Comment: Could you set a breakpoint on `return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)` line and run your application in debug ? Does your debugger stop?

Comment: Have you added `@Import(SwaggerConfig.class)` to your spring boot bootstrap class ?